# Combine lines whenever string matches in the file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, solaris

I would like to combine two lines whenever the particular string is found in the file.

**Sample Input:**

```
{
    id: 23281598
      total: {
        value: 3.0
      }
      isThin: false
      raw: {
        value: 6.0
      }
    }
    total: {
      value: 1.401326182E9
    }
    Pools: {
      value: 8.98886247E8
```

**Desired Output:**

```
{
    id: 23281598
      total: { value: 3.0
      }
      isThin: false
      raw: { value: 6.0
      }
    }
    total: { value: 1.401326182E9
    }
    Pools: { value: 8.98886247E8
```

As you notice, whenever i find the pattern `value:` I want to combine it with previous line in the file. I am okay if you remove the leading white spaces in each line. I need `awk` or `sed` solution. There is no fixed pattern in the input file. The line containing `value:` may occur anywhere but it will not occur consecutively.

Using Solaris 5.10.

Comment: Is this actually a JSON file?  In that case, the newlines does not matter (to a proper JSON parser).

Answer (score 1):

POSIXLY:

```
LC_ALL=C sed -e '$!N;/value:/b1' -e 'P;D' -e:1 -e 's/\n[[:space:]]*/ /' <file
```

It's straight forward:

- `$!N`: with each line except the last one, reading the next line
- `/value:/b1`: if pattern matches, go to branch named `1`
- `P;D`: if pattern does not match, print the current line, start new cycle with reading line from `$!N` above. So if you have `line1\nline2`, then print `line1`, start new cycle with `line2`, `$!N` make it to be `line2\nline3` and so on.
- `:1`: defines branch named `1`
- `'s/\n[[:space:]]*/ /'`: in branch `1`, replace embedded newline and leading spaces with one space.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple:

```
sed 'N;s/\n[[:space:]]*value:/ value:/;P;D'
```

Do an `N;P;D` cycle to always process two lines at once (no `$!` needed here btw). Inside replace a newline with spaces followed by `value:` with a single whitespace. That's it.

Comment: I think you can use `[[:blank:]]` here...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `sed` also

```
sed -e '/: {$/{N;s/\n//g}' -e 's/{.*v/{ v/g' file
```

Explanation:

- `/` start condition
- `: {$` if line ends with `: {`
- `/` End condition
- `{` Start operation group
- `N;` concatenate the line below to the matching line
- `s/\n//g` makes the replacement of `\n`
- `}` End operation group

Optional for formatting output

- `'s/{.*v/{ v/g'` execute other expression where replace all between `{`&`v` (spaces) to one single space

Is my understanding solaris doesn't support `-i` option, so you must do a redirection of the output to make the changes.

Give a try

Comment: You realized that only lines with `value: ` should be joined? In this example there are no other cases, but think of something like `name: {\n  string: "tachomi"\n}`. And your `s/{.*v/{ v/g` is really dangerous.